# Laravel Pagination not working after setConnection() on eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to create a model in Laravel 8.x that can use different databases (Dynamically). It is currently working by setting the connection after creating an instance of the model, using Laravels build-in "setConnection" function. However, pagination on the model is not working. I get the following error:

`(PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.times' doesn't exist`

The problem is that the "test" database, is not the one I am currently telling the model to connect to. I am connectin to 'mysql_timer'. Is pagination reseting the DB connection to default or?

You can see my controller code here:

```
public function getStats(Request $request)
    {
        $query = new Time;
        $query->setConnection('mysql_timer');

        $query = $query->with(['user']);
        
        $data = $query->paginate($length);

        dd($data);
    }
```

And my "Time" model:

```
class Time extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'times';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'uid';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'uid',
        'mapid',
        'runid',
        'mode',
        'style',
        'rectime',
        'recdate',
        'strf_num',
        'jump_num'
    ];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'uid', 'uid');
    }
}
```

Comment: may I ask why are you trying to set connection in the controller. Why are you not using `.env`. It makes sense if you have multiple databases and you are trying to connect.

Comment: I do set the connection details in the .env file - but the model needs to know which connection to use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on($connection)` to begin querying the model on a given connection:

```
$data = Time::on('mysql_timer')->with(['user'])->paginate($length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getStats(Request $request)
    {
        $query = DB::table("mysql_timer.times as times)
                 ->join("users", "users.id", "=", "times.user_id")
                 ->paginate($length);

        dd($query);
    }
```

did u try like that?

Comment: This is working for me. But I would like to stay with eloquent models. Are there no way of accomplishing that?

Comment: class Times extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $connection = "mysql_timer";
    protected $table = "times";
    protected $guarded = [];

}

Comment: create model i shown as above.

Answer (score 0):

First make model

```
php artisan make:time
```

After go model

```
protected $connection = "mysql_timer";
protected $table = "times";
protected $guarded = [];

public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

After go controller

```
$query = Time::query()->with("user")->paginate($length);

dd($query);
```

Comment: The problem with this is, i would like for the $connection (Database) to be dynamic. At one instance i would like it to be 'mysql_timer' and at another 'mysql_timer2' (As an example). This can not be accomplished with what you are suggesting.